# Login PHP no funciona segunda vez

Tags: php, html

Tengo un `HTML` para un `login` y me he encontrado que, cuando el usuario y contraseña son erróneos, al hacer un segundo `click`, me da acceso.

El problema es, que utilizo como comprobación:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EMPLEADOS WHERE Usuario= :usuario and contraseña= :pass
```

y se da el caso de que hay varios empleados que no tienen usuario y contraseña.

El segundo `click` sobre el `login`, recoge valores en blanco de los campos de usuario y contraseña y la `SELECT` devuelve un valor mayor que cero y eso es lo que he utilizado como condición de acceso.

```
$numRegistros=$resultado->fetchColumn();

    if($numRegistros>0){
        session_start();
        $_SESSION["usuarioLogeado"]=$_POST["usuario"];
        echo "Num registros: ".$numRegistros;            
        //header("location:tablas.php");

    }else {  
       header("location:index.php?error=true");

    }
```

La pregunta es por tanto, si se puede controlar ese problema de alguna manera.
Gracias.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Lo doy por cerrado.

Comment: Si tienes `empleados` que no tienen usuario y contraseña, es lógico que cuando intentes logearte sin completar los datos el `login` funcione, _ya que encuentra al menos un registro que donde el usuario y contraseña son vacíos_. Como ves TODOS los empleados deben tener un `usuario` (**único**, es decir, no puede haber 2 con el mismo `usuario`) y una `contraseña`. Ademas, no olvides implementar el recuperar contraseña.

Comment: Si existen usuarios que no tienen `Usuario` y `Contraseña` no deberías dejar los campos vacíos tal cual, deberías asignarles en su lugar un `NULL` para evitar que se conviertan en combinaciones válidas. Por otro lado, ten cuidado si permites que los usuarios puedan modificar su campo `Usuario`, ya que podrían hacerse pasar por otros usuarios fácilmente porque veo que no son campos únicos.

Comment: Luis si lo das por cerrado, marca una como respuesta por favor, así otra persona podrá saber como resolviste el problema. Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para empezar debes solucionar el problema en tu base de datos, no debes permitir que existan usuarios sin contraseñas.

Y despues cambia tu `SELECT` a algo como esto:

```
SELECT id FROM EMPLEADOS WHERE USUARIO = :USUARIO AND PASS = :PASS
```

El campo `id` he supuesto que lo tienes, sino pon otro.

La condición ahora seria mas ajustada y real.

Pero repito que es **fundamental** que arregles lo de la base de datos.
Si necesitas ayuda con esto dilo.

Espero que te sea útil, y si lo es no te olvides de marcarlo como respuesta.

Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Aunque esta bueno que evites tener usuarios sin contraseña, muchas veces no se puede lograr ello (por diferentes motivos).
Es por esto que puedes optar por comprobar que el usuario y la contraseña no estén vacíos, antes de realizar la consulta.

Luego, consultar por el usuario y la contraseña.

Comment: Esto parece relamente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]